# get .mov video rotation with php or avconv

Tags: php, linux, libav, avconv, mediainfo

is there a way to find an `.mov` file's rotation from the exif data directly with php or using `avconv`?

Im currently using `mediainfo` but I was wondering if I can get the rotation without depending on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libav's avconv does not support it, at least not [yet](https://lists.libav.org/pipermail/libav-devel/2013-December/054374.html).

However, `FFmpeg -i` will show you the metatada of the video and you can find the `rotate` attribute in there.